# Deduplicating Bash Brace Expansions

Tags: bash, wildcards, brace-expansion

Brace expansions can produce multiple instances of file names if there is an overlap in the matches.

A simple example:

```
mkdir testdir; cd testdir
touch abcd
for f in *{b,c}*; do something_to "$f"; done
# or more simply:
ls -l *{b,c}*
```

That is a very simplified example just for illustration. In this case, the single file `abcd` would be processed (or listed) twice.

How can this list be best deduplicated?

- An associative array could be used.
- A carefully crafted glob/brace expansion could be used, but that's not robust.

Comment: `zsh` has the same behavior.

Comment: @jordanm: Thanks, How's it going?

Comment: What's *not* robust is combining shell globs with brace expansion.  Shell globs by themselves are perfectly robust, you just have to know what you're doing.

Comment: @Wildcard: There's nothing wrong with using globs and brace expansion together. Believe me, [I know what I'm doing](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/topusers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes,

```
for f in *{b,c}*
```

is first expanded to:

```
for f in *b* *c*
```

And then the loop runs over the independent expansion of those two globs.

What you want here is one glob. Here, `*[bc]*` would do, but for anything more complex, in `bash`, you'd need to enable ksh-like extended globs. You'll probably want the nullglob option as well:

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob
for f in *@(b|c)*; do...
```

In `zsh`:

```
for f in *(b|c)*(N); do
```

The `(N)` being for a per-glob `nullglob`.

In `ksh93`:

```
for f in ~(N)*@(b|c)*; do
```

Comment: The key to the deduplication is the vertical bar **or** operator whereas the brace expansion is implicitly an **and** operation which just *begs* for duplication.